# TikZ package: coordinate from intersection of arc and line

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, arc

I've been trying to create a handful of intersections of an arc and lines.

Here's my code:

```
\coordinate (A) at (0, 5);
\coordinate[label=below:$M$] (B) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (C) at (5, 0);
\path[name=arc1] (C) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=5cm];
\coordinate (D) at (intersection of arc1 and 1,0--1,5); % throws error
            
\draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (5, 5); % draw grid
\draw[line width=0.5mm] (A) -- (B) -- (C) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=5cm] -- cycle; % draw quarter circle
```

[image: Desired Intersections]

The yellow spots in the image are where I want those intersections to be.
LaTeX throws an error at `(intersection of arc1 and 1,0--1,5)` because apparently `arc1` is not defined, even though I wrote `[name=arc1]` when defining the arc.

Comment: you have to follow the correct syntax of `intersections` library. You can check pgf manual, `Section 13.3.2 Intersections of Arbitrary Paths` https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: multiple intersections]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
        \coordinate (A) at (0, 5);
        \coordinate[label=below:$M$] (B) at (0, 0);
        \coordinate (C) at (5, 0);
        \draw[name path=arc] (C) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=5cm];
        \path[name path=lines] (0,0) -| (1,5) -| (2,0) -| (3,5) -| (4,0);
        \fill[name intersections={of=arc and lines, name=i, total=\t}][yellow,opacity=0.5,every node/.style={above right,black,opacity=1}]\foreach\s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s)circle(2pt)node{\footnotesize\s}};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```